# AWS: redshift query taking too much time. How to troubleshoot this

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have an aws redshift database

I am trying to run a simple sql query

the table has only 32 columns

```
select * from dbname.tablename order by id desc limit 10;
```

Its taking taking a lot of time

[image]

What to do. how understand the issue.

the explain command output

```
explain select * from dbname.tablename order by id desc limit 10;
```

[image]

Comment: How many rows are in the table? What is the SORTKEY on the table? Is it a 'normal' table or a Redshift Spectrum table? How long does it take?

Comment: how to know its a normal table or redshift spectrum table

Comment: Wow! 865 million rows and 1063 columns?! You really don't want to do a `SELECT *` on that!

Comment: the table has only 32 columns

Answer (score 1):

You are asking Redshift to read and sort nearly a billion rows at what looks like 1000 columns wide.  This is going to take a minute.

You only want the top 10 ids so you can break this up and do a lot less work.  If you have a reasonable idea of what the max id is then you can add a WHERE clause to only read (and sort) rows that are near this value.  Your estimate doesn't need to be very close - just get the number of rows down to a million or so :)

Try:

```
select * from dbname.tablename where id > <some reasonable guess> order by id desc limit 10;
```

It would be best if your table is sorted by id (and analyzed) to save on the scan step but even if it isn't the sort phase will be less as the data will still be pruned down.

If you have no idea at all what the max id is you can make improvements by having Redshift find the max id in the query.  The cost of this is scanning the table twice but the first time it only needs one column (id).

```
select * 
from dbname.tablename 
where id > (select max(id) from dbname.tablename) - 1000
order by id desc 
limit 10;
```

In general it is a good idea to reduced data as early as possible in a query when working with large amounts of data.